# Add a new tableView in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView which shows array contents.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   //currnet table information.
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    if chartTitle[indexPath.row] == "Name" {
        cell.textLabel?.text = chartTitle[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if ... {
        ......
    }       

    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return chartTitle.count
}
```

Now I want to add a new tableView which shows another array's content but it is difficult for me to implement since both tableView has the same class UITableView.

How to add a new tableView and manage its rows dependent on another array?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test in your function `cellForRowAtIndexPath`and other like `numberOfSectionsInTableView` , `numberOfRowsInSection`, etc :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

    if tableView == self.firstTableView {
          // do something 
    } else if tableView == self.secondTableView {
           // do something else 

}
```